# Getting 404 errors in IIS 7.0

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-7

I set up a website in IIS 7.0 the same way I have done it many times elsewhere, but keep getting 404 errors externally. Internally, everything loads fine. I have tried to set up logging, but nothing goes through and it may very well be because I am less familiar with how the logging works or where to look for it. I can see the IIS page when typing in the host, but anything past that will return 404.

I have very limited knowledge on the subject and any articles I find have too much jargon. Does anyone have any ideas on what or where I can look?

I found the error: iis 7.5  Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/5.1.2600 404

But I have the WebDAV Publishing role turned off.

Comment: You need to give us more information.

Comment: I added a little more information. If you ask for any particular information I can give it to you, but I honestly don't know what would help.